# Change default expiry period of "Pyotp"

Tags: python, python-3.x, one-time-password

I'm using Pyotp for generating OTP. Default expiry of this token is 30sec. How can I change the default expiry to some 60 seconds?
This is the simple code I'm using.

```
secret = pyotp.random_base32()
totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret)
otp = totp.now()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here, give this a try, It did work for me.

```
totp = pyotp.TOTP(secret, interval=60)
```